# How to add a blank lines in C# application developed in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, addition, blank-line

I want to add blank line between two lines.I have more code likes an example.

```
        errorStructObj = new ErrorStruct(0, ErrorStruct.errorMainType.ExceptionError, ErrorStruct.errorEventType.Non_Wcf, ErrorStruct.errorEnvironmentType.Database, ErrorStruct.errorOperationType.Asynchronous, ErrorStruct.messageShownEnvironment.ClientAlert, "EXCCE00004", "Hata! Hata Kodu : EXCCE000004");
        Program.errorStructFactoryNesne.AddErrorStructListeler(4, errorStructObj);
        errorStructObj = new ErrorStruct(0, ErrorStruct.errorMainType.ExceptionError, ErrorStruct.errorEventType.Non_Wcf, ErrorStruct.errorEnvironmentType.Database, ErrorStruct.errorOperationType.Asynchronous, ErrorStruct.messageShownEnvironment.ClientAlert, "EXCCE00005", "Hata! Hata Kodu : EXCCE000005");
        Program.errorStructFactoryNesne.AddErrorStructListeler(5, errorStructObj);
        errorStructObj = new ErrorStruct(0, ErrorStruct.errorMainType.ExceptionError, ErrorStruct.errorEventType.Non_Wcf, ErrorStruct.errorEnvironmentType.Database, ErrorStruct.errorOperationType.Asynchronous, ErrorStruct.messageShownEnvironment.ClientAlert, "EXCCE00006", "Hata! Hata Kodu : EXCCE000006");
        Program.errorStructFactoryNesne.AddErrorStructListeler(6, errorStructObj);
```

Comment: Click at the end of the line and press enter? What is your issue?

Comment: what do you mean. enter?

Comment: Could you use a for loop here?

Comment: i have 3000 lines codes for each lines enter?

Comment: Visual Studio supports regex in find/replace.

Comment: I would strongly recommend finding a better way to write the above code.  The amount of duplication is obscene.  At the very least, look into T4 templates to generate this kind of code for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VS press `ctrl+shift+H` in find options check the `Use Regular expression` in search term type `\n` and for replacement term type `\n\n`, pressing `ctrl+A` will replace all.

Comment: `\n` will be considered as `\\n`. so visual studio cant find it. i dont know how OP was able to do it.

Comment: you need to use regexp. Updated